# BinaryFormatter serialized object from .NET Framework 4.8 won't deserialize in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, deserialization, backwards-compatibility, binaryformatter

I'm adapting a older application written in .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 6 due to a new version of an API that it uses. There is unchanged logic that serializes and deserializes models created by the API using BinaryFormatter. However, there is a strange cross-compatibility issue as below:

- Model serialized in .NET 4.8 -> Model deserialized in .NET 6.0 - Fails
- Model serialized in .NET 6.0 -> Model deserialized in .NET 4.8 - Works

The exception is "System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Invalid BinaryFormatter stream.'" and the inner exception is "ArgumentException: Type '<my type>' is not deserializable."

Assembly names and types appear to be correct in my deserialization binder, which is the extent that I'm able to step deeper into this code. I'm moreover puzzled how, if assembly versions from my app are the culprit, that going from 6.0 to 4.8 succeeds.

My research into this issue has only come up with a few issues such as this one (https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/35346) but that involve .NET Core. I understand that BinaryFormatter is deprecated and has security issues per the MS documentation, but converting everything to use JSON/XML is not really a realistic solution at this point.

Is anyone aware of issues affecting BinaryFormatter backwards compatibility in more contemporary .NET versions?

Edit: As requested here is a minimally reproducible example. I don't want to share any of my actual code or types but it appears that System.Random suffers from a similar problem as well:

```
// .NET Framework 4.8
FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Create);
try 
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(fs, new Random()); 
}
catch (SerializationException) { throw; }
finally { fs.Close(); }

FileStream fs2 = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Open);
try
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter2 = new BinaryFormatter();
    var randomObj = formatter2.Deserialize(fs2); // Succeeds
}
catch (SerializationException) { throw; }
finally { fs.Close(); }

// .NET 6.0
FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Open);
try
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    var randomObj = formatter.Deserialize(fs); // Fails
}
catch (SerializationException){ throw; }
finally { fs.Close(); }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Stack Overflow isn't for querying others to see if they have similar issues: it's to explain your issue, then those who are knowledgeable about the subject can help find a solution. And though you've described your issue, that [mcve] will go a long ways towards others being able to reproduce and experiment to find a solution.

Comment: Backward compatibility was always *not guaranteed*. All advice from Microsoft said not to do this. The choice to use it for long-term persisted data was a time bomb, and not just a time bomb but one that was *not at all secretly* a time bomb. You'll have to write a .NET 4.8 tool to read it and convert it to something else.

Comment: .NET6 **is** .NETCore, so the github issue applies.  You need to show at least a stack trace.

Comment: may be if you use something like BSON from third party like Newtonsoft, you will get bin. serialization/deserialization working between 2 different .net frameworks

Comment: Be aware that even if you somehow got this to work again in .NET 6, from .NET 7 onwards the obsolescence of the APIs is [upgraded from a warning to an error](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/7.0/binaryformatter-apis-produce-errors), meaning that that is your final stop regardless (although it looks like they still give you an out by explicitly setting "I know what I'm doing, honest" flags -- but I wouldn't be surprised if the *next* version then takes the final plunge and removes the code completely).

Answer (score 1):

There are known risks in using BinaryFormatter for serialization and deserialization of objects - particularly across versions of framework.

Please have a look at the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide) which actively discourages using binary formatter for serialization/deserialization of objects using binaryformatter.

Also, .Net 5 onwards the deserialization operation on binaryformatter throws an exception of type NotSupportedException. Refer to exceptions tag on this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.deserialize?source=recommendations&view=net-7.0) for more information.